# How to send the image to the email box?

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am using PHPmailer (http://phpmailer.worxware.com/) class to send form information via emails. Inside the form there is an image like this:

```
<form.....>

<div><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(42, 42); ?></div>


</form>
```

How do I send that image via an email? Thank you.

Comment: Please elaborate.Your image is in any field ?

Answer (score 2):

Either use the `AddAttachment` method or compose an HTML mail and include the image as a `src` link.

attachment: http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/wiki/AdvancedMail
link:  http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/wiki/BasicMail

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a file input field through which you uploaded the image to the server you won't be able to send it via PHPMailer (or in any other way for that matter).

```
<form>
    ...
    <input type="file" />
    ...
</form>
```

That is if you actually want to send the image attached to the email. If on the other hand you want to send an email which has the image code embedded in the email body itself then I guess you are looking for a way to send an HTML email, which are also supported by PHPMailer. Here is an example how you would do that (take note that the image itself would need to be publicly accessible).

```
<?php
/**
* Sending an HTML email through PHPMailer and SMTP...
*/
require_once('PHPMailer.class.php');

$mail = new PHPMailer(true); // the true param means it will throw exceptions on errors, which we need to catch

$mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP

try {
    $mail->CharSet = 'utf-8';
    $mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;                     // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Host       = "smtp.example.com"; // sets the SMTP server
    $mail->Port       = 587;                    // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
    $mail->Username   = "user@example.com"; // SMTP account username
    $mail->Password   = "password";        // SMTP account password
    $mail->AddReplyTo('user@example.com', 'Sending User');
    $mail->AddAddress('user_2@example.com', 'Receiving User');
    $mail->SetFrom('user@example.com', 'Sending User');
    $mail->Subject = 'Image';
    $mail->AltBody = 'To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!'; // optional - MsgHTML will create an alternate automatically
    $mail->MsgHTML('<html><body><img src="http://example.com/path_to_image.jpg" width="xxx" height="xxx" /></body></html>'));
    $mail->Send();
    echo "Message Sent OK<p></p>\n";
} catch (phpmailerException $e) {
    echo $e->errorMessage(); //Pretty error messages from PHPMailer
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage(); //Boring error messages from anything else!
}
?>
```

As for HTML emails they have their own set of rules and best practices. I.e. if you intend on doing anything more complicated than sending an image you should use a CSS inliner like [this one](http://beaker.mailchimp.com/inline-css), avoid using some of the stuff like `background-image` etc.

Comment: if the image is not <input type="file" /> how do i do? it is generated by the php.

Comment: I already explained it that you have two options to send an image to the user via email: attachments and HTML emails. For attachments you need to have the image uploaded to your server through an <input> field. For HTML emails you just need to have the image publicly available.